# How to stick rows to the column that genarated by the query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have two sheets, `Data1` and `Data2`. The first column of `Data2` is generated based on formula `=QUERY(Data1!A2:A)` so it just mirror the `Data1 A` column.

[image]

The rest of the columns within `Data2` are manually inserted.

So if there any changes in `Data1 A` column the `Data2` will became broken because in that case `Data2 A` will get a new values but all the rest columns/rows will remain same position.

[image]

I wonder if it is possible to freeze the rows or something in `Data2` sheet to avoid the problem.

Here is a link to the [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZwslzGZA4lic6Tna5glyTyD6VW7TBFgjE6uBTb3R7N4/edit)

Comment: What is your reason for creating a dynamic formula in the first place?

Comment: Please read carefully this text - [**"Solving the Dynamic / Static Data Alignment challenge using Alignment Index Numbers"**](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649/solving-the-dynamic-static-data-alignment-challenge-using-alignment-index-numbers?hl=en). When you solve your problem using the techniques outlined there, you can post the answer to your question here (and I will gladly vote for it)

Comment: @BlindSpots just to avoid copy-pasting and making sure that all columns are in use, otherwise you can make mistake when copy pasting, etc

Comment: @JohnSUN would you mind sharing a sample sheet?

Comment: @JohnSUN is it the one I had to use https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X0_y6xsxCcaXvg7_IcB1RQYiyAjmIl7wjbNJYdActi4/template/preview ?

Comment: @sreginogemoh Yes this. Or you can create your own. It's not about the template, but about the principle used - a unique index for each row of data in both tables - both in the main table and in the resulting one.

Comment: @JohnSUN do you think it is fit my particular case?

Comment: @sreginogemoh Yes, I do. Have you read all the text, all eight parts (maybe part of the text was hidden and you need to click the button to "load 5 more replies")? Doesn't the description of the problem in the first and second posts exactly match your problem?

Comment: You are asking us to create you a relational database. What do you want to happen when someone deletes an id from table1 do you want all the information you had in table2 deleted? How about when someone enters a duplicate in table1 or deletes it in table1 and then readds the same one later? Is ID a unique identifier that will never be duplicated? Will ID’s ever be deleted or just new ones added?

Comment: @CodeCamper I do have a validation for unique ID's using data validation formula, however I don't care about handling a deletions, all I care is properly handling a modifications of that key column of Data1 sheet. So not really trying to replicate relation db using sheets as it may seems like, however I think that would be nice to have feature

Comment: @sreginogemoh if you don’t care about deletions then what kind of modification could possibly cause the rows to be misaligned?

Comment: @CodeCamper However if deletion will ever happen that will result cleaning up both tables, which is fine. So yeah all I care is adding a new ones or reordering current ones.

Comment: @CodeCamper for example insertions in between rows. Currently if I had to insert a new row in Data1 table or reorganize the order I had to disable formula within Data2 table, to modify the rows accordingly, but when there is a lot of data changes like that involved it is not quite convenient to do so. So deletions are not as painful and won't  happen as often as insertions in that case if you see what I mean.

Comment: @sreginogemoh is there a reason why you can’t just sort the query by the order I’d so that they always stay in the same order? Then if an id is deleted it will create an issue but row insertions and additions won’t matter anymore.

Comment: @CodeCamper This is just example sheet there, in reality I do have a string not a number there, so had to stick to the custom order to keep the sheet structure